# How to use custom post type and taxonomy for car specs in wp

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am planning to develop a new car specification website.
I want to create a new type post for single page car specs.
But I need guidance for the structure of taxonomies.

First there is the **Brands page**:

```
BMW
Benz
Volvo
And..
```

If I choose BMW for example. there is the **Series page**:

```
Series 1
Series 2
Series 3
And...
```

And if, for example, I choose series 3, I will enter the page of **Generations** of this series:

```
E21
E21 facelift
E30
And..
```

And if I choose E21 for example:

I enter the **specifications page** of this car.

Url: mysite{dot}com/cars/bmw/3-series/e21

How to do these layers with wordpress taxonomy and post type?

Comment: Could this be done with a single taxonomy and child terms the same way you might do with nested categories? I'm not seeing where the complexity is coming from, it would just have a more general name such as "car category" instead. Otherwise you'd need 3 taxonomies which is doable but why go to the effort

Comment: Tnx @TomJNowell, If I use a single taxonomy, can I display each layer with a different style?
Each layer, for example, the 2nd generation of the 3-series of the BMW brand, has a title image, description, and other meta data.
And if I use 3 taxonomies, How do I connect them together? It means that the user can view the BMW series after entering the BMW brand page